# Disk Size Considerations for a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, disk-space

What's the rule of thumb for Disk size considerations for hosting a mirrored database that supports about 100 writes every second during peak. Current database full **back up size** is approx 150 MB.

Considering (separate) drives for

- Data
- Log
- TempDb

Database size from `exec sp_spaceused` is (will take care of huge DB size, it's bloated because of mirroring I reckon)

```
database_name   database_size   unallocated space
-------------------------------------------------    
APP_PROD        88026.31 MB     0.00 MB

reserved    data        index_size  unused
--------------------------------------------    
122168 KB   118992 KB   2088 KB     1088 KB
```

Many thanks

Comment: There are more factors to consider than you've disclosed here.  Are you using SSDs? How big do you expect the data to grow and how fast?  Do you care more about reducing hardware costs or do you consider your time as more of a cost?  When you say 100 writes is that 100 database changes (write transactions), 100 pages written, or what?  How much do you use the tempdb (peak page reads/writes/sec)? Do you have sufficient RAM such that your cache hit ratio is at least 99.9%? What is your page life expectancy during peak usage?

Comment: Are you using SSDs? No
How big do you expect the data to grow and how fast? Close to 3000 records per day on a table containing approx 50 columns. 
Do you care more about reducing hardware costs or do you consider your time as more of a cost? Front end talking to this DB is a real time system - time in terms of speed is critical.
When you say 100 writes is that 100 database changes (write transactions), 100 pages written, or what? 100 write transactions during peak time.

Comment: How much do you use the tempdb (peak page reads/writes/sec)? Not so many temp tables etc. Application uses high in memory caching, and only frequent writes on a particular table.
Do you have sufficient RAM such that your cache hit ratio is at least 99.9%? RAM - 16 GB, neven seen usage more than 5 GB.
What is your page life expectancy during peak usage? (Will get back on this, not the peak time, but current is 920396.

Comment: 100 writes per second. Inserts,  updates  or deletes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need exactly the same disk space for your mirrored (secondary) database as for the primary database. They are the same and **the secondary database will have the same growth rate as your primary database and should be provisioned the same**.

SP_SPACEUSED will show you how much space your primary database is now using (you should make it larger and not rely on autogrowth), and you can grab growth information from the default trace to give you some limited information about how often the database has grown, you can then infer the growth rate from the autogrowth parameters.

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT 
   DatabaseName,
   [FileName],
   SPID,
   Duration,
   StartTime,
   EndTime,
   FileType = CASE EventClass 
       WHEN 92 THEN 'Data'
       WHEN 93 THEN 'Log'
   END
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE
   EventClass IN (92,93)
ORDER BY
   StartTime DESC;
```